# Multiple place holders in a Select command appear awkward. Asking if ok

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested array for example:

```
myVals = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 3, 15, 7}, {2, 3, 35, 106}};
```

And suppose I want to select in each sub-array, all elements not equal to 3, then:

```
Select[#, # != 3 &] & /@ myVals
{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}
```

seems to work but I think it's awkward as the place holders # actually represent two different items:  The first # is a sub-array like {1,2,3,4,5,6}, and the second one represents each item in that sub-array.

Is this a standard way of doing this in a one-line command?  I'm running 12.3.

Comment: try `DeleteCases[myVals, 3, 2]` and `Cases[#, Except[3]] & /@ myVals`?

Comment: if you have to use `Select`, try `Select[#, x|-> ! x == 3] & /@ myVals`

Comment: @kglr:  Noticed if I have real vals in array and use Abs[x], DeleteCases won't work: myVals = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0.001}, {20, 20, 21, 3, 15, 7, 
    0.00001}, {2, 3, 35, 106, 0.001}};
DeleteCases[myVals, Abs[#] < 0.0001 &, 2]  But the Select syntax you posted does work.  Thanks!

Comment: josh, the second argument in `DeleteCases` (and in `Cases`) should be a _pattern_. That is, you should use something like `DeleteCases[myVals, x_ /; Abs[x] < 0.0001, 2]`.

Comment: kglr, thanks for the info about using patterns.  That works nice and is simple to understand for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is clearer

```
Select[#, Function[x, x != 3]] & /@ myVals
```

Comment: That works nice Chris and also works in my case where I'm removing real numbers such as: Select[#, Function[x, Abs[x] > 0.01]] & /@ myVals

Answer (score 4):

```
DeleteCases[#, 3] & /@ myVals
```

OR:

```
myVals /. 3 -> Nothing
```

OR:

```
Select[#, x |-> x != 3] & /@ myVals
```

OR: (* using operator forms only*)

```
Map[Select[UnequalTo[3]]][myVals]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

myVals = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 3, 15, 7}, {2, 3, 35, 106}};
```

Use the operator form of [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
Select[# != 3 &] /@ myVals

(* {{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another variation with [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select) that avoids using any hashes:

```
Select[UnequalTo[3]] /@ myVals
```

> {{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

And a variation with [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases) that also avoids using hashes:

```
DeleteCases[3] /@ myVals
```

> {{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 3, 15, 7}, {2, 3, 35, 106}};
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[Except @ 3] /@ list
```

{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

Using `DeleteCases`

```
DeleteCases[list, 3, {2}]
```

{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[list, Position[list, 3]]
```

{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[#, {3}] & /@ list
```

{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

Using `SubsetReplace` (new in 12.1)

```
SubsetReplace[{3} :> Nothing] /@ list
```

{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 3, 15, 7}, {2, 3, 35, 106}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
list //. {a___, 3, c___} :> {a, c}

(*{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}*)
```

Or using `Replace` at level `2`:

```
Replace[list, 3 -> Nothing, {2}]

(*{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[list, {{a___, 3, c___}} :> {a, c}]

(*{{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {20, 20, 21, 15, 7}, {2, 35, 106}}*)
```